# Disabling unused streams for openni_launch

Tags: openni-launch, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using openni_launch to start my kinect. Per default it publishes a lot of topics (IR, Depth, RGB in mono, rectified, registered, compressed, theora versions).

I would be interested if it is possible to disable the unused topics per launch file to increase performance? Or is it necessary to change the sources?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51986/disabling-unused-streams-for-openni_launch/) by [Fabian Saccilotto](https://answers.ros.org/users/2806/fabian-saccilotto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-01-11**:
Don't expect to much performance incrementation if any at all; Usually those topics' computations are paused if no node is subscribed. The kinect isn't even switched on until someone subscribes. (Beside that, your question is valid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As felix says, there shouldn't really be a performance difference, since processing won't be done unless a particular topic is subscribed to. It would be possible to add arguments to openni.launch to disable launching of certain nodelets (and therefor get rid of certain topics), but there are already a fair number of arguments to the launchfiles and I'd rather not add more.

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0